# Tags behaving oddly this New Year's Day

Tags: bug, tag-search

Several times this morning I have clicked on a tag ([python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) in my case) and received odd results -- a bunch of questions that do not have that tag, or no questions at all!

Is something going on today?

Comment: I cant repro this

Comment: The tag-engine is still drunk from New Years celebrations ....

Comment: The tag engine went to the party, and was cornered by the site-search function; it may never recover.

Comment: Sounds like a cache was being rebuilt or something :)

Comment: From what I heard: nothing changes on New Year's Day.

Comment: I'm seeing similar behavior from RSS feeds (MSE):  [RSS feeds returning wrong tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/385546/rss-feeds-returning-wrong-tags)

Comment: Happened again just now.  Page says I am viewing `python`.  Not an actual python tag anywhere to be seen.  They do all have `vaadin` tags, which is nice I suppose.

Comment: Has there been any movement on this?  There are other reports of similar issues (on MSE): [RSS feeds returning wrong tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/385546/173290) and [Is it possible for the RSS feed to erroneously publish questions that don't match the query?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/386084/173290).  An update would be great.

Comment: @gregsdennis Just as a data point, I saw it happen again earlier today.

Comment: I'm getting it on multiple feeds now.

Comment: @Ethan it seems to happen intermittently.  I can't repro it at will either.  Please see the other issues that I linked in a comment above for a more detailed explanation of efforts to analyze the problem.

Comment: Just got another one of these a minute or so ago for https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=manatee.json+or+json-everything&sort=newest. I immediately looked at the feed content, and all looked correct.  Not sure why it momentarily has unrelated questions.

Comment: I've just updated my answer below with results from another feed.  `json-path` tag results in two `telegram` questions.  Is there a mismatch in tags somewhere?  Did IDs get scrambled in the DB?

Comment: I haven't seen this for a couple weeks.  Was it explicitly addressed or did the problem just disappear?

Comment: I got it again, March 4th @gregsdennis . So still definitely a problem. I'm using Slack's RSS app to consume tag feeds, which it does weekly. For the tag we specified, this is one or two posts every so often, but lately when it runs, it selects a seemingly random tag (this week it appears to be [numpy] ) and returns dozens of posts we don't want. However, if I examine the feed in Outlook's RSS reader, everything's fine.

Comment: Do we have any indication that folks at Stack Overflow/Prosus are aware, have noted the reports and/or are dealing with the issue? It's baffling that the only official response to one of these queries is in relation to the use of logical operators, not the random tag inclusions.

Comment: I just got it again, too.  I'll update below.

Comment: There are already four or five questions here in Meta tracking the same problem https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387370/152193, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423071/554319, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/385546, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/386084. I repeat @DermotCanniffe question: is there any indication that the team is working on this? It's really annoying.

Comment: I can confirm it is an issue.  Intermittently every week or so a request returns some other tag (at the moment we get "stripe" instead of "commercetools" but last week it was some specialised C language topic).  If you check manually a minute after, the feed is correct again.

Comment: Checking manually doesn't help when you've automated your reader to feed into a reporting system.  I have a feed reader in Slack that just generates a bunch of spam each time this happens.  That doesn't self-correct.

Comment: Still happening in April.  Can we get some feedback on whether this is actually being worked on, please?

Comment: Still happening.. just got a batch of bad results this morning.. happens intermittently

Comment: This is STILL happening!!!  Can we get this fixed, please?  Every month, I have Slack channel that is flooded with questions that are unrelated to the feed I've subscribed to.  Then, when I look at the results of the feed, all of the listed questions are correct.  I'm not sure where these questions are coming from, but something is definitely broken.

Comment: And again, just now.

Comment: Just happened again a minute ago.

Answer (score 4):

Not an answer, but I wanted to log the questions that I got from a recent spurt so that maybe a cause could be identified.

All of these were reported at 19:44:38 UTC from https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=manatee.json+or+json-everything&sort=newest (questions tagged `[manatee.json]` or `[json-everything]`).

Lots of Python and Django, which is completely unrelated to the .NET-oriented tags, along with some other miscellaneous stuff.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75337741/suggest-me-some-ideas-for-my-2nd-year-mini-project-in-web-technology
- [Convert series datetime data into total hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75338471/convert-series-datetime-data-into-total-hours)
- [Find specific link on a website with Selenium (in Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75341448/find-specific-link-on-a-website-with-selenium-in-python)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75341672/web-scraping-espn-soccer-webpage-with-python
- [How can I find a dynamic url on a webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75342544/how-can-i-find-a-dynamic-url-on-a-webpage)
- [ISO-8859-1 response encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75343242/iso-8859-1-response-encoding)
- [Using Google Identity Service to create a sign up button but nothing is displayed in popup window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75344097/using-google-identity-service-to-create-a-sign-up-button-but-nothing-is-displaye)
- [Django & SQLite.db - data is duplicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75344684/django-sqlite-db-data-is-duplicated)
- [How to scrape all values from a table like HTML DIV structure without missing some of them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75347474/how-to-scrape-all-values-from-a-table-like-html-div-structure-without-missing-so)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75348312/python-flask-request-form-getname-world-not-passing-default-vlaue
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75349391/mongodb-database-malfunction
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75350206/trying-to-load-a-static-css-file-and-it-doesnt-work
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75350300/cant-create-a-normal-html-in-django-python
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75350799/parser-html-which-separates-tag-img-for-telegram
- [Navbar doesn't direct to a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75351353/navbar-doesnt-direct-to-a-url)
- [How to link to python file inside html code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75354678/how-to-link-to-python-file-inside-html-code)
- [Trying to run a for loop on a html element while using bs4 but it does not iterate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75355518/trying-to-run-a-for-loop-on-a-html-element-while-using-bs4-but-it-does-not-itera)
- [The checkout form gets skipped but the database updations are being performed right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75355693/the-checkout-form-gets-skipped-but-the-database-updations-are-being-performed-ri)
- [Python - replace some text in html only between p-tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75355719/python-replace-some-text-in-html-only-between-p-tags)
- [How to keep JavaScript values between multiple pages in one session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75356007/how-to-keep-javascript-values-between-multiple-pages-in-one-session)
- [Is there any way to pass a long javascript array to a python script which is using python cgi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75357048/is-there-any-way-to-pass-a-long-javascript-array-to-a-python-script-which-is-usi)
- [Python read html table from confluence and print each row as list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75359880/python-read-html-table-from-confluence-and-print-each-row-as-list)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75360443/my-live-server-extension-does-not-execute-instead-is-just-taking-me-to-a-downloa
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75361220/script-to-pass-id-to-website-and-return-core-set-of-attributes
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75363322/how-to-hide-current-image-url-class-based-view-django
- [Prevent duplicated scans in a single QR code scan in DJango](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75364594/prevent-duplicated-scans-in-a-single-qr-code-scan-in-django)
- [Can a webpage have multiple HTML tags in the same page? what does html[2] mean in xpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75364834/can-a-webpage-have-multiple-html-tags-in-the-same-page-what-does-html2-mean-i)
- [How do I filter data in a ForeignKey Django to display the corresponding data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75365120/how-do-i-filter-data-in-a-foreignkey-django-to-display-the-corresponding-data)
- [Plotly Callbacks Dynamic Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75365853/plotly-callbacks-dynamic-table)

Edit (16 Feb 2023, 20:36 UTC):

Just received two questions about Telegram from feed that's supposed to return questions tagged with `json-path`.

Feed URL: https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=jsonpath&sort=newest

Questions:

- [Telegram Bot throws error only when published](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75464438/telegram-bot-throws-error-only-when-published)
- [Auto starting telegram bot when somebody join the channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75466051/auto-starting-telegram-bot-when-somebody-join-the-channel)

Edit (08 Mar 2023, 08:34 UTC):

[image: capture of slack feed]

- [How to resolve "Your Bitbucket token is no longer valid. Please re-authenticate." in Visual Studio App Center without disconnecting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75561414/how-to-resolve-your-bitbucket-token-is-no-longer-valid-please-re-authenticate)

Same feed as above.

Edit (18 Apr 2023, 21:36 UTC)

Two questions with the `[eclipse-scout]` tag, not `[json-everything]`

- [Eclipse Scout BuilderParts createConstraints() take string input for search query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75616820/878701)
- [Storing data from Wix database in external database or using webhooks in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76030675/878701)