# RSS feed for a tag erroneously including other data

Tags: bug, rss

I have a [Slack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slack_(software)) channel subscribed to https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/osquery this has worked great for several years. However, there have been two recent occurrences where we got a slew of posts with unrelated tags.

On 2023-01-25, we got a bunch of things tagged with `ios`. I didn't count these, maybe 50? They had a bunch of tags, but `ios` looked like the common one.

On 2023-02-06, we got about 10 things tagged `pattern-matching`. As before, there's a bunch of tags, but `pattern-matching` is the common one.

Update: On 2023-02-17 we got a bunch tagged `passwords`

I don't have much insight into the server or caching side here, but this all seems like a bug in there.

Comment: Possibly duplicate or related to: [Tags behaving oddly this New Year's Day](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422443/tags-behaving-oddly-this-new-years-day)

Comment: I tried to search, but didn't find anything. Anyhow... In addition to that link, I see:
[RSS feeds returning wrong tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/385546/rss-feeds-returning-wrong-tags) and [Is it possible for the RSS feed to erroneously publish questions that don't match the query?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/386084/is-it-possible-for-the-rss-feed-to-erroneously-publish-questions-that-dont-matc) (MSE)

It all seems like a pretty clear bug.

Comment: Also experiencing this - appears to happen on a weekly basis

Comment: It's happening to us as well https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387370/152193

Comment: Yep, this has been going on for a while...

Comment: It just happened again at 19:08 UTC with the `kedro` feed of Stack Overflow.

Comment: for the record, we have the same exact problem..   RSS subscription sometimes returns batch of messages unrelated to the subscribed tag.. happened again this morning.

Comment: Same same here. Looking for `[rascal]` but we get lots of hits on python related questions. Not mistagged.

Comment: I get this iffy feeling of a hash collision somewhere. The other results are totally unrelated. It makes no sense from a distance. So I'm guessing at a tricky bug in the query for tagged questions or a filter on all questions by tag.