# Only Android-source questions in [python] tag

Tags: bug, tags

I tapped on the [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag (URL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) and got a list of questions which were only tagged with [android*]:

[image: newest tab]

(The screenshot is low quality because I wanted to show a lot of questions.)

With the search bar and filter widget open:

[image]

Note: the Python question at the top only appeared after I tapped on "1 question with new activity".

Other than that, the first question is [Give my app permission to trigger a factory reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77605272/give-my-app-permission-to-trigger-a-factory-reset) while the last question is [How is AOSP build process optimizing my system app's native libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77287303/how-is-aosp-build-process-optimizing-my-system-apps-native-libraries). It looks like it's all the newest [android-source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-source) questions.

Loading the page again fixed this issue, but I think it's concerning that it happened even once.

Possibly related: [RSS feed for a tag erroneously including other data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423071/6083675)