# Too few (only two) entries on active tab of C++ tag

Tags: bug, status-review, homepage

I always use the ["Active" tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b?tab=active&pagesize=50) when looking for questions to answer. But around 10 minutes ago I noticed a weird behavior (possible bug) which is that the "Active" tab only showed 2 questions instead of showing 50.

This happened for the first time since I am using this tab. Also, even after refreshing the page 2 times, it still showed only 2 questions. But after refreshing a third time, all 50 entries were shown.

Is this a bug of some kind? Just reporting for future reference. I am also attaching a screenshot of the same.

[image]

---

Here is the URL that *temporarily* showed this bug:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b?tab=active&pagesize=50

---

**Update 2024 Jan 18**

This happened again today and below is the screenshot:

[image]

**Update 9 Feb**

Today also I faced the same issue and this time I recorded the screen. Here is the video I recorded to show the same. Note instead of showing 50 entries, the page only shows around 10 or 15 entries. Many of them even don't have the c++ tag.

Links to see the video showing the issue since the video file is 25 mb:
https://postimg.cc/0znPTmqj

Comment: Oh, also neither of the two questions has the C++ tag. Seems like a bug with the search results.

Comment: @VLAZ I don't have any [ignored-tags] set. But I do have two [watched-tags] set which are `c++` and `python-3.x`.

Comment: Turns out it's irrelevant. Sorry. I thought it might be something where 48 of the questions on the page happened to be ignored and hidden. But as I said, the questions you get aren't even for C++. Definitely a search bug.

Comment: @Gimby Note also the url at the top of the page. In particular, the url contains the active tab of the c++ tag only. So randomness doesn't seem relevant here.

Comment: I just checked, I see all C++ questions. I refreshed a couple of times, the view does not change. Eh. Blame it on (server) caching?

Comment: @Gimby Yeah, I have actually saved that page for the last 3 years or so and have continuously(everyday for last 3 years) used that page but this possible bug came to notice for the first time. Everyday I refresh it 100s of times but this never happened before(at least when I was refreshing or nobody reported it).

Comment: I had a similiar bug recently, where https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python returned me questions for completely different tag (can't remember which one though). Refreshing fixed the issue.

Comment: @matszwecja [Same exact thing here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/427421/6083675) but with the newest questions. I suspect this is happening to a number of people once or twice but they just refresh the page and don't report it.

Comment: For such questions, please provide a link to the page on which you see the bug/issue. This makes it easier and quicker for other users to check to see if they experience the same issue. That's particularly helpful with something like this, which appears to be intermittent, as making it easier for users to go to the exact affected page will result in significantly more views of the page and increase the likelihood of someone duplicating the issue. Such a link also ensures that people are actually looking at the same page (something that's prevented duplication on other reports).

Comment: In addition, moderators, or at least I, like to see an issue duplicated, preferably by ourselves, but by at least one other user, prior to adding a [meta-tag:status-review] tag, which is what forwards the issue to SE's internal ticketing system, which then gets routed to developers as a bug/feature request.

Comment: For this issue, I assume that you were looking at the [C++ tab active questions page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b?tab=Active).

Comment: @Makyen Here is the exact url that temporarily showed this bug: [Active tab bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b?tab=active&pagesize=50). I've added the same in my question.

Comment: @Makyen This happened again today and I've added a screenshot for the same in the updated question.

Comment: @Makyen I've encountered this issue 2nd time today as shown in the screenshot. I think this should make this to be `status-review` taggable?

Comment: I have just encountered same error on "Newest" tab of [tag:c++]. The page shows results related to databases.

Comment: @Makyen This time I recorded the screen to have some kind of proof that the issue is real. Here is the [link](https://postimg.cc/0znPTmqj) to the video. The `status-review` should be added now.